# Zend Framework 2 TableGateway Select error

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to know how many reservations are made at `$reservation_datetime`. I wrote this code however I have error

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Reservations\Model\ReservationTable::Reservations\Model{closure}() must be an instance of Reservations\Model\Select, instance of Zend\Db\Sql\Select given, called in /home/.../vendor/zendframework/zend-db/src/TableGateway/AbstractTableGateway.php on line 190 and defined in /home/.../module/Reservations/src/Reservations/Model/ReservationTable.php on line 99

The line 99 is:

```
$this->num = $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) {
        $select->columns(array('num' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('COUNT(*)')));
        $select->where(array('reservation_date' => $reservation_datetime));
    });
```

Of this code

```
class ReservationTable
{
    protected $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    public function saveReservation(Reservation $reservation)
    {
        $data = array(
            'reservation_date' => $reservation_datetime,
            ...
        );

        $reservation_spot = (int)1;
        $rsn = $this->getReservationCount($reservation_datetime);
        if($rsn < 4) {
            for($i=1; $i<4; $i++){
                if($rsn = $i) {
                    $reservation_spot++;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new \Exception('No available spots');
        }

    }

    public function getReservationCount($reservation_datetime)
    {
        $this->num = $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) {
            $select->columns(array('num' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('COUNT(*)')));
            $select->where(array('reservation_date' => $reservation_datetime));
        });

        return $this->num;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgot to include the `Select` class from Zend. At the top of the class add this line.

`use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;`

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;

class ReservationTable
{
    protected $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    public function saveReservation(Reservation $reservation)
    {
        $data = array(
            'reservation_date' => $reservation_datetime,
            ...
        );

        $reservation_spot = (int)1;
        $rsn = $this->getReservationCount($reservation_datetime);
        if($rsn < 4) {
            for($i=1; $i<4; $i++){
                if($rsn = $i) {
                    $reservation_spot++;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new \Exception('No available spots');
        }

    }

    public function getReservationCount($reservation_datetime)
    {
        $this->num = $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) {
            $select->columns(array('num' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('COUNT(*)')));
            $select->where(array('reservation_date' => $reservation_datetime));
        });

        return $this->num;
    }    
}
```